# IEBGENER with multiple input file

Tags: mainframe, jcl, utilities

I am new to the mainframe.
I have a job and this step in the JCL seems a bit confusing.

```
//*----------------------------------------------------------
//*       IEBGENER
//*----------------------------------------------------------
//GENER02  EXEC PGM=IEBGENER,COND=(8,LT)                     
//SYSPRINT DD   SYSOUT=I                                     
//SYSUT1   DD   DSN=&&FILE1,DISP=(OLD,DELETE)                
//         DD   DSN=&&FILE2,DISP=(OLD,DELETE)                
//         DD   DSN=&&FILE3,DISP=(OLD,DELETE)                
//SYSUT2   DD   DSN=&&OUT1,DISP=(NEW,PASS),              
//         SPACE=(TRK,(100,100),RLSE),UNIT=WORK,             
//         DCB=(LRECL=90,BLKSIZE=22950,RECFM=FB)             
//SYSIN    DD   *                                            
  GENERATE MAXLITS=100                                       
  RECORD FIELD=(20,'                    ',,1),               
         FIELD=(28,'                            ',,21),      
         FIELD=(16,'AB110000AB012561',,49),                  
         FIELD=(26,'                          ',,65)         
/*
```

I know IEBGENER is a copy utility, but with 3 input file and that parameter, what exactly the output file is going to be ?
Does it combine the 3 files ?

Comment: What has this to do with Cobol ???. The 3 input files will be read one after the other

Comment: why don't you run the JCL and see what happens ???; Here is a link to the record statement: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.idau100/u1132.htm

Comment: I don't have any environment to run it. I am trying to understand the statement meaning only by Google. IBM's links quite hard to understand without example

Comment: I'd suggest breaking this into two questions; I'm trying not to confuse matters.  One has to do with how DD statement concatenation works; one has to do with what this specific job does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second question of what the output will look like.  The way this is coded it looks like it is removing fields from the output and putting in spaces in their place.  Basically it will be something like this:

**Input Record**

```
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
This is my input data to IEBGENER so I can see what the output records will look like ....
```

**Output Record**
Note: the `_` represent the spaces inserted based on your utility FIELD statements.

```
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
________________________________________________AB110000AB012561__________________________
```

Effectively the IEBGENER job does not copy any data but places the one literal in the output dataset.

It looks like you also need a MAXFLDS=4 or you'll get a message:

`IEB342I INVALID SPACE ALLOCATION`

Comment: Thanks for your example. Does it mean to place 90 bytes literal to the last record? Your example show that it replace the last input record to the new 90 bytes literal of sysin, am I right? This is coded in an already running system btw,  I have no authority to edit it btw :D

Comment: I took your example and ran it to confirm and it does it on every record.  I'm not sure what the purpose is unless its simply creating a new output file with the same number of records as the input datasets with the one literal replacing them.  So, if you had 100 input records you'd have 100 output records that are exactly the same.

Comment: thank you so much. I am investigating the step meaning, so run on actual machine like that helps alot

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is yes.  z/OS concatenates all the DD cards in a DD statement into one logical bundle, and then processes them together.  See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.ieab600/iea3b6_Syntax4.htm

The longer answer is that you're looking at things from a file (dataset in z/OS terminology) point of view; much of z/OS isn't structured that way.  z/OS utilities tend to look at things from some sort of data oriented point of view, usually referred to as records or record blocks; in the example above, IEBGENER is going to look at each record it is given via SYSUT1, do some processing (documented here:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.idau100/u1132.htm), and then write the output to SYSUT2.  IEBGENER isn't even really aware that there are multiple input datasets; it just asks the operating system for the next record from SYSUT1, and z/OS will respond, and then IEBGENER tells z/OS to write the output record to SYSUT2.

Comment: Really appreciate your explanation. A little wonder about the RECORD FIELD process. Does it edit all the record to a new literal record defined in FIELD?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to practice with a real mainframe system, I suggest the MVS 3.8 Turkey 4- system.  It starts with Free MVS 3.8 from 1980 with system fixes to May 1985, running on an emulator with user develop programs to replace some copyrighted software, other are missing.  99.99% of what it does you can do on z/OS 2.3, some features have been updated and other features have been added.  Some projects that rely on newer features won't run.